# Update microcode

Tags: bios, acpi, firmware

I have almost latest intel CPU and my computer simply doesn't power off. `dmesg`:

```
[    4.761241] ACPI: Invalid passive threshold
...
[    7.329946] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT1._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190703/psargs-330)
[    7.329951] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_GTF]
[    7.329952] No Arguments are initialized for method [_GTF]
[    7.329952] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT1._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190703/psparse-531)
[    7.331230] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT1._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190703/psargs-330)
[    7.331234] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_GTF]
[    7.331234] No Arguments are initialized for method [_GTF]
[    7.331235] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT1._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190703/psparse-531)
[    7.331601] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT0._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190703/psargs-330)
[    7.331606] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_GTF]
[    7.331606] No Arguments are initialized for method [_GTF]
[    7.331607] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT0._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190703/psparse-531)
[    7.348220] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.SAT0.PRT0._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190703/psargs-330)
```

Launching `iucode_tools` says that microcode can be updated:

```
selected microcodes:
  064/001: sig 0x000906e9, pf_mask 0x2a, 2019-10-03, rev 0x00ca, size 100352
  065/001: sig 0x000906ea, pf_mask 0x22, 2019-10-03, rev 0x00ca, size 99328
  066/001: sig 0x000906eb, pf_mask 0x02, 2019-10-03, rev 0x00ca, size 100352
  067/001: sig 0x000906ec, pf_mask 0x22, 2019-10-03, rev 0x00ca, size 99328
  068/001: sig 0x000906ed, pf_mask 0x22, 2019-10-03, rev 0x00ca, size 100352
```

... but I can't figure out how to do this. Running just `sudo apt-get upgrade intel-microcode` doesn't help at all (upgrade is made but nothing changes).

Comment: The bios errors way be something to do with your problem. However the CPU micro-code is not the BIOS code. So two separate things. Please split into two separate questions.

Comment: You're viewing a list of microcodes intended for multiple different Intel CPUs. What's the exact command you're running? You can view the microcode revision that's currently in use with `grep microcode /proc/cpuinfo | uniq`.

Comment: I run `/usr/sbin/iucode_tool -tb -lS /lib/firmware/intel-ucode/*`.
`grep microcode/proc/cpuinfo | uniq` returns `microcode : 0xca`. Maybe I was wrong about microcode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already implied in the comment by user263096 if you use the BIOS to boot just update your BIOS using your motherboard manufactures website and install the latest Intel drivers.

Even tho this is quite unlikely I would also check the

```
/boot/loader/entries/entry.conf
```

file if

```
initrd  /cpu_manufacturer-ucode.img
```

is there. If not, add it.
This only makes sense if you use uefi.

EDIT: If you are using GRUB try

```
/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: My `/boot/grub` directory doesn't have any `entries` dir.

Comment: try /boot/grub/grub.cfg if that does not exist, you probably don't have uefi. Just try updating the Bios and drivers then.

Comment: If you're using GRUB, the microcode file should be included in your initramfs/initrd file for an "early microcode update" i.e. update before the kernel is fully started, which is the current recommended method. With `iucode-tools --overwrite -S -K microcode.dat` the correct microcode for your CPU will be written in the proper location at `/lib/firmware/intel-ucode/`, then use your distribution's tools to regenerate your initramfs file (`update-initramfs -u` in Debian/Ubuntu, `dracut -f` in some versions of RHEL/Fedora, etc.)

Comment: I have only `AuthenticAMD.bin` in `initrd`. And yes, I failed, I have BIOS, not UEFI.